# New Scroller - not scrolling after replacing div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a News Scroller that get's it's headlines from another website. If I hard code the new items like this, everything is fine:

```
<div id="featured" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #E1DAC0; border-top: 1px solid #E1DAC0;">
    <div class="newsitem"><div class="newsthumb">
        <a href="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/news-newpagechristmas_spirit_breaks_down_interface_barriers">
            <img src="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/thumbnail-xmas_market-jpg-20618-1-1-0.gif" height="63" width="87" alt="Christmas spirit breaks down interface barriers" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="news-newpagechristmas_spirit_breaks_down_interface_barriers" title="">Christmas spirit breaks down interface barriers</a></h2>
    <div class="newsdate">4 Nov 2014</div>
</div>
<div class="newsitem">
    <div class="newsthumb">
        <a href="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/news-dispelling-myths-in-east-belfast">
            <img src="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/thumbnail-east_belfast_racism_seminar_i-jpg-20587-1-1-0.gif" height="63" width="87" alt="East Belfast racism seminar" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="news-dispelling-myths-in-east-belfast" title="Housing Executive dealing with the myths about racism in east Belfast">Dispelling myths in East Belfast</a></h2>
    <div class="newsdate">27 Oct 2014</div>
</div>
<div class="newsitem">
    <div class="newsthumb">
        <a href="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/news-junior-wardens-back-on-the-city-streets">
            <img src="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/thumbnail-newbuildings_primary_school_junior_wardens-jpg-20557-1-1-0.gif" height="63" width="87" alt="Newbuildings Primary School Junior Wardens" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="news-junior-wardens-back-on-the-city-streets" title="Our Junior Warden project has started again in local primary schools in Derry-Londonderry. ">Junior Wardens back on the city streets</a></h2>
    <div class="newsdate">22 Oct 2014</div>
</div>
<div class="newsitem">
    <div class="newsthumb">
        <a href="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/news-the-railway-runs-again-at-strule-and-centenary">
            <img src="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/thumbnail-omagh_strule_train_mural-jpg-20499-1-1-0.gif" height="63" width="87" alt="Omagh Strule train mural" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="news-the-railway-runs-again-at-strule-and-centenary" title="Local people, events and images have been combined to create a new entrance feature at Strule Park and Centenary Park.">The railway runs again at Strule and Centenary</a></h2>
    <div class="newsdate">16 Oct 2014</div>
</div>
</div>
```

the scrolling is done using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.cycle/2.99/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#featured").cycle({cleartype: false, easing: 'easeInOutQuad', 
            fx: 'scrollDown', speed: 3500, speedIn: 1000, speedOut: 1000 });
    });

    window.onload = function initialLoad() {
        document.getElementById("page-inner");
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }
    window.onerror = function () { return true };
```

When I comment out the newitems, and use this javascript function to get the news items, the scroller does not work, and the four items appear together:

```
    var pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    pageRequest.open("GET", "http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/", false);
    pageRequest.send();
    var pageSourceCode = pageRequest.responseText;
    var n = pageSourceCode.indexOf('<div id="featured">');
    var n2 = pageSourceCode.indexOf('<div id="pager"></div>');
    var extract = pageSourceCode.substring(n, n2);
    extract = extract.replaceAll('href="', 'href="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/');
    extract = extract.replaceAll('src="', 'src="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/');
    featured.innerHTML = extract;
```

The new function correctly goes away and gets all the HTML in the div id="featured". It correctly replaces the div on the current page. It just fails to do the scroll.

When I run this with FireFox using FireBug, I get the following error on the console: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at touch.nihe.gov.uk. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

On the other hand, running in IE, that console displayed this message: [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1. Is it somehow getting its number of slides before the new divs have been copied in?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try restarting cycle after XMLHttpRequest:

```
var pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    pageRequest.open("GET", "http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/", false);
    pageRequest.send();
    var pageSourceCode = pageRequest.responseText;
    var n = pageSourceCode.indexOf('<div id="featured">');
    var n2 = pageSourceCode.indexOf('<div id="pager"></div>');
    var extract = pageSourceCode.substring(n+21, n2);
    extract = extract.replaceAll('href="', 'href="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/');
    extract = extract.replaceAll('src="', 'src="http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/');
    featured.innerHTML = extract;
    $("#featured").cycle({ cleartype: false, easing: 'easeInOutQuad', fx: 'scrollDown', speed: 3500, speedIn: 1000, speedOut: 1000 });
```

Comment: When I run this with FireFox using FireBug, I get the following error on the console: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://touch.nihe.gov.uk/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: On the other hand, running in IE, that console displayed this message: [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1. Is it somehow getting its number of slides before the new divs have been copied in?

Comment: Note: var extract = pageSourceCode.substring(n+21, n2)
without +21 extract contains div id=featured and create div with id=featured in another div with same id

Comment: Alessandro Marchisio - that was a good solution. I changed that line to exclude the div tags: var extract = pageSourceCode.substring(n+19, n2-6); It works in IE now. FireFox and Chrome are more fussy.